# get src of an iframe

Tags: c#, razor

Im trying to get the src of an iFrame with regex, but cant seem to get this to work, and cant quite figure out what the problem is, so was hoping for a bit of help here - The problem is the condition is never met ? :)

The code:

```
var iframe = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/oyoew4T74_w\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

            Match matchdec = Regex.Match(iframe, @"\ssrc='\b(\S*)\b", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (matchdec.Success)
            {
                if (matchdec.Groups.Count > 1)
                {
                    var retval = matchdec.Groups[1].Value;
                    <div class="video-link">
                        <a class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-9" data-filmtitle="@childNode.GetProperty("sliderItemTitle").Value">
                            <span>Se trailer</span>
                            <div class="iframelink" style="display:none">@retval</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                }

            }
```

Comment: Ahhh, was matching for the sign: ' and not "

Comment: Needed to change it to: Regex.Match(iframe, @"\ssrc=""\b(\S*)\b", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);